# Why my limit on CPU does not validate via cgroups

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups

/etc/cgconfig.conf

```
...

group memlimit {
    memory {
        memory.limit_in_bytes = 8589934592;
    }
}

group cpulimit {
    cpu {
        cpu.shares = 1024;
    }
}
```

/etc/cgrules.conf:

```
@gatewayer  memory  memlimit/
@gatewayer  cpu cpulimit/
```

And I've restarted services via commands:

```
service cgconfig restart
service cgred restart
```

After I execute my python script from user who belongs to group `gatewayer`, I could see the PID when executing `cat /cgroup/memory/memlimit/cgroup.procs` and the limit have been applied on the running process. However, limit on cpu does not take effect, and `cat /cgroup/cpu/cpulimit/cgroup.procs` doesn't print the PID as expected.

I tried to check on the process, and it turns out to be the same result, that memory is limited by cgroups whereas cpu is not:

```
$ cat /proc/18113/cgroup 
174:blkio:/
173:net_cls:/
172:freezer:/
171:devices:/
170:memory:/memlimit
169:cpuacct:/
168:cpu:/
167:cpuset:/
```

Could anyone give me some help? Many thanks.